# Canvas Base64 Issues

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cross-browser, base64

```
    <body>
        <input type="button" onClick="toBase64();" value="To Base 64"/>
        <textarea id="data" rows="20" cols="80"></textarea>
        <br>
        <canvas id="canvas" width="490" height="220"></canvas>
        <br>
        <img id="echo">
        <br>
    </body>


 function toBase64() {
      var can = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var base64 = can.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById('data').value = base64;
        $('#echo').attr("src",base64);
    }
```

Outputs : "data:image/png;base64, LONG HEX STRING"

Using the above code, prints the canvas and outputs the base 64 without any issues.

The only issue is whening doing this in differnt browsers listed below:
-Firefox
-QT webkit
-Chrome

The output base64 size is very differnt..

e.g String length

QT 600,000  roughly

Chrome 3200 roughly

Firefox 600 roguhly

Is there any parameters i can send toDataUrl? to force the same about across browsers or at least more similar?

e.g. to DataUrl("image/png","quality")  quality been a number?

Any other recommendations?

Comment: Since difference browser use different encoder, getting same size will not be possible. What is your use case?. Is it for testing.

Comment: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement), yes, you can pass image type and quality parameters. The difference in size could be different browsers using different image types or levels of compression

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome toDataUrl quality param is not effect when export jpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20278017/chrome-todataurl-quality-param-is-not-effect-when-export-jpeg)